# Partial record keys as required keys of another object

Tags: typescript

`parametersAccessConfig` should only require keys that `parametersConfig` actually has where as what it does now is ignore that the `parametersConfig` is a partial and requires all the keys. How do I write a type which only requires the listed properties?

> Type '{ NEW_UI: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Record': LIMIT_ACCOUNTS and DARK_UI.

```
enum Parameter {
  NEW_UI = 'NEW_UI',
  LIMIT_ACCOUNTS = 'LIMIT_ACCOUNTS',
  DARK_UI = 'DARK_UI',
}

const parametersConfig: Partial<Record<Parameter, boolean>> = {
  [Parameter.NEW_UI]: true,
}

const parametersAccessConfig: Record<keyof typeof parametersConfig, string> = parametersConfig;
```

Basically `keyof typeof parametersConfig` lists all `Parameter`s rather than only those actually included in the object.

Comment: By annotating `parametersConfig` as `Partial<Record<Parameter, boolean>>` you have thrown away any more specific information from the initializer.  You will be able to write `delete parametersConfig[Parameter.NEW_UI]` or `parametersConfig.LIMIT_ACCOUNTS = false;` and the compiler doesn't keep track of these.  As far as the compiler is concerned, `parametersConfig` may or may not have any or all of the keys in `Parameter`.  So `keyof typeof parametersConfig` is just `Parameter`.

Comment: If you don't want this to happen, don't annotate `parametersConfig` at all, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WyerJW).  And then `parametersAccessConfig` is probably unnecessary. Can you articulate why you think you need to annotate `parametersConfig` in the first place?  Seems like an unstated premise.

Comment: `parametersConfig` does not have access to all the data `parametersAccessConfig` has so what I did was create a new object and map it to all `parametersConfig` keys but not exactly all `Parameter`.

Comment: You haven't explained why you need to annotate `parametersConfig` at all, though. What, specifically, goes wrong if you don't do that?  With your example I get [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgZY9W) and everything works as I expect.  If that doesn't meet your needs, please [edit] your question with a [mre] that demonstrates why.